# Some windows are blurry

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

I'm learning tkinter and I noticed that the widgets are a little blurry, I know it's just visual bug but it only happens on my computer.

[image: example]

I tried to fix it restarting the pc, drivers, but nothing has worked, I also realized that is not a Tkinter problem, it happpes with all the windows that are similar to tkinter window. What can I do to fix it?

[image: Another app]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mre]. Show us your code and your attempt to solve the problem, as we can't help you if we don't know what you've tried.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This typically happens when you're running a tkinter app on a display with higher DPI than tkinter expects (i.e., most modern displays). Fortunately, you can easily configure your app to be "DPI-aware".

You can set the `PROCESS_DPI_AWARENESS` state for your app by using the Windows "shcore" DLL via the built-in `ctypes` module like so (sounds complicated, but it's just two lines - see below):

```
import tkinter as tk
from ctypes import WinDLL  # import this class so you can use Windows DLLs

# make this process DPI-aware
shcore = WinDLL('shcore')  # access the Windows "shcore" DLL (library)
shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)  # call "SetProcessDpiAwareness"
# NOTE: if you want to know what that 1 means, see the link below this code


# this is all a guess based on that screenshot
# since there's no code attached to this question
# (put the rest of your code below here)
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x150')

label = tk.Label(root, text='Hello, world!')
label.pack(anchor='nw')
btn = tk.Button(root, text='Click me', width=10, height=2)
btn.pack(anchor='nw')

root.mainloop()
```

For what it's worth, this happens in those other (non-tkinter) apps for the same reason - they aren't DPI-aware!

If you really want to get into the weeds, you can read more about the Windows shellscalingapi [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellscalingapi/nf-shellscalingapi-setprocessdpiawareness)

Note that there are some caveats to this method, and that it doesn't take into account any scaling factor that you may have set in Windows under display settings, e.g. 150%. UI scaling differences (in conjunction with DPI awareness settings) can cause your app to look different depending on the display used to view it! There are already a few good answers regarding UI scaling available, so I won't cover it here.